# Rails+DelayedJob: How to display a status that the Delayed Job task is running/is done?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job, status, polling

I am processing a task that needs some time, so I am thinking about assigning this task to Delayed Job. Would be quite user-friendly to display to users an information about status of the currently processed task - like "processing" and "done".

Checking out the official [Github page](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) and I see there some `success`, `after`, etc methods, but how to use them?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I used DelayedJob effectively in my project. The following procedure works fine for me. 
Assume we have a module or class like Subscription and I call a method which was defined as an module method using delayed job as follows:

> Subscription.delay(:queue =>
>   "insertion_order_#{advertiser.advertiser_id}",:priority =>
>   1,:record_of =>
>   request_tracker.record_of).pull_data(advertiser,date,Insertionorder)

Now if you want to track error,success or any other hooks then you have to define them in the module or the respective class as follows

```
module Subsciption
  def self.error(job, exception)
    puts "Error occurred"
    sleep(160)
  end
end
```

Means all those hooks are working on the object which is used for background processing.

Comment: @user984621 Is this useful?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I am still trying to figure out how to use this procedure on my problem - all I do is calling a single line `Subscription.delay.cancel_subscription(user)` - so do I have to create a special module `Subscription` for it? And in the view, how to display the information whether a task is being processed/done? (Sorry, it's a bit confusing for me)

Comment: Is Subscription a class or a module in your project?

Comment: I think in your case, just define a self method inside of a Subscription class. Then it will work fine

Comment: `Subscription` is a controller class and a model (not a module). But how can I call the method from the model/controller if I don't know the parameters (`job`, `exception`)? Or - how do I get them?